animateDpAsState increasing an image to the right end causing not equal offset in LazyRow
I have implemented a LazyRow containing 25 cells, and I need to meet two simple requirements:
When the app is launched, the LazyRow should automatically scroll to position the middle cell at the center of the screen. For instance, with 25 cells, cell #13 should be centred on the screen, allowing the user to scroll both left and right.
The cell in the center should be twice as large as the other cells.
Visually, the expected result looks like this:

However, there's an issue on the first launch. Although the screenshot above shows the desired appearance (after some manual scrolling), the initial appearance looks different:

As you can see, once the center cell enlarges, it pushes the adjacent cells on the right side out of alignment. This happens because the animation increases the cell size starting from the top-left corner and expanding to the right.
The question is: how can I adjust the animation so that it expands the center cell equally to the left and right, ensuring that it appears as expected on the first launch (as shown in the first screenshot)?
Here's the code:
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateDpAsState
import androidx.compose.animation.core.snap
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.snapping.rememberSnapFlingBehavior
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListItemInfo
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyRow
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.derivedStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun JustRotator(
    number: Int = 25,
    cellSize: Dp = 75.dp
) {
    val listState: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    LaunchedEffect(number) {
        val idx: Int = number / 2

        listState.centerItemBy(
            idx = idx,
            animationSpec = snap()
        )
    }

    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        state = listState,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = listState)
    ) {
        items(count = number) { idx ->
            val isCenterItem: Boolean = listState.isItemInCenter(idx)

            val animatedSize: Dp by animateDpAsState(
                targetValue = if (isCenterItem) (cellSize * 2) else cellSize,
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300),
                label = ""
            )

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(animatedSize)
                    .clip(CircleShape),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_profile_chooser_lock),
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LazyListState.isItemInCenter(
    idx: Int,
    withOffset: Int = 0
): Boolean {
    val isItemInCenter: Boolean by remember(this, idx) {
        derivedStateOf {
            val visibleItemsInfo: List<LazyListItemInfo> = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            val screenCenter: Int = (layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset + layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset) / 2

            val centeredItemIdx: Int = visibleItemsInfo.minByOrNull { itemInfo ->
                val itemCenter: Int = (itemInfo.offset + itemInfo.size / 2)
                kotlin.math.abs(screenCenter - itemCenter)
            }?.index ?: -1

            (centeredItemIdx + withOffset) == idx
        }
    }

    return isItemInCenter
}


Right now scrollToItem only scrolls to the left position, so you should take that into account when calculating the scroll-to position. There's a feature request to add the ability to scroll to a custom anchor, like scroll to center, you can vote for it to get more attention.
Your centerItemBy implementation is missing in the question, so I can only guess what could've went wrong there.

You need to offset half of the container width so that the cell with the target index is centered.
You need to offset half the size of the cell. Don't forget that this centered cell is twice the size of the other cells.

val density = LocalDensity.current

LaunchedEffect(number) {
    val idx: Int = number / 2
    val centerCellSizePx = with(density) { cellSize.roundToPx() * 2 }
    listState.scrollToItem(
        index = idx,
        scrollOffset = (-listState.layoutInfo.viewportSize.width + centerCellSizePx) / 2
    )
}

The result is perfectly centered

